# How to connect 2 Models in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want the user show page to display the content of the user’s first micropost.
I already have user that accepts name and email and micropost that accepts the post and user id. My guess is I need to connect the user of the micropost to the id of user but i don'tknow how.

Comment: Hi, and welcome on StackOverflow. It sounds like you're following Michael Hartl's _Ruby on Rails Tutorial_. Your best chance to get an answer it to provide more details, which will also make your question easier to be found and more useful for other users. For example, add the code you already have, what you expect it to do, and what's happening instead.

Comment: If you return @user.microposts, what happens?  Or, if you prefer, if you enter User.first.microposts in the console, what happens?  It sounds like you either need to set up the associations in the models or you may have them set up and don't know how to access associated objects.

Comment: Result of @user.micropost is #<Micropost::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f7700138fc0>. User.first.microposts gets the the infromation that I want. I already have has_many: microposts in my user and belongs_to to Micrposts. Where should I put the code to get the User.micropost.first?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is to make a simple model relation. You can do this by defining the relationship in the relevant model file.

Lets say you wanted to link the post to the user based on a foreign key relationship linking the user_id field on post to the id field on user. In the posts model file, do something like this:

```
belongs_to :user
```

That lets ruby know how to structure the queries properly when joining data across models.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description in question you should have something like

***app/models/user.rb***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Migration
  has_many :microposts
  # attributes :id, :name, :email
end
```

***app/models/micropost.rb***

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  belongs_to :user
  # attributes :id, :user_id, :post
end
```

Comment: I already have these in my code, what should i do next to get the value of User.first.microposts and show it in the html file?